# Generate and download excel file from .Net core Web Api returns 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to generate and download an excel file from .Net Core web Api. This web api has hosted in azure app services. Excel file generated using EpPlus package. This file generating by passing a date range and a few other parameters. The size of the file depends on the date range. When I provide 1 day for the date range file download without an issue since the size of the file is small. When I give large date range server returns "500 - The request timed out".

I tried remote debugging on azure app service and it takes only 2 minutes to complete the request and return the respponce. But it does not return to the web browser

This is my web api get method

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetReport(String StartDate, String EndDate, bool SIH, bool FinalOrder, bool Allocations, Boolean GRN, bool ActualSale, bool Buffers, bool FillRate, bool Forecast)
    {
       //Generating exel file in to a byte[] using EpPlus package here
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();

        const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";


        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

        var fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(stream, contentType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = "Infor-Report.xlsx"
        };

        return fileContentResult;

    }
```

This is my web.config file in azure app service

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\JMSL.OMS.BackEnd.API.dll" requestTimeout="00:20:00" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
  <environmentVariables />
</aspNetCore>
```

And my program.cs

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
        })
        .Build();
```

What I am doing wrong here? Your feedbacks are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to enable the fail request tracing to see which module handle so long time and you could generate a full dump for the process and use debugdialog analysis to analysis the dump file to find out the reason.

About how to use FRT in Azure, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/27/enable-failed-reuqest-tracing-for-an-azure-app-service-web-app/).

About how to capture dump, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/07/01/create-a-memory-dump-for-your-slow-performing-web-app/)

About how to use  debugdialog analysis to analysis the dump file ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump).